# Select Case with Like

Tags: vba, visio

I want to move objects based on a string.

[image]

I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAS0guHvJZk&ab_channel=VigilIT-video

My code looks like this:

```vb
Sub finalsort()
Dim DiagramServices As Integer
DiagramServices = ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled
Dim ViPage As Page
Set ViPage = ActiveDocument.Pages("SLD")
Dim vShp As Visio.Shape
Dim subShp As Visio.Shape
Dim Shpname As String

Dim sel As Visio.Selection

For Each vShp In ViPage.Shapes
    For Each subShp In vShp.Shapes
        Select Case subShp
            Case subShp.Characters.Text Like "*AA**"
                ActiveWindow.Select vShp, visSubSelect
                vShp.Cells("PinY").Formula = "80mm"
                vShp.Cells("PinX").Formula = "180mm"
        End Select
    Next subShp
Next vShp

End Sub
```

No error, but also no action.

Comment: `Select Case` used when you have many variants (cases). In your answer I can see single variant with `Like` function. Is there reasons use `Select Case`?

Comment: I've prvided just one as an example. Finall I would have another Like AB,AC,AD etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read about [Select Case Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/using-select-case-statements) syntax!
I found this article [VBA select case like: operator, string, statement](https://ccm.net/apps-sites/software/2125-vba-using-the-like-operator-with-select-case/), please look at chapter [How to use the True expression](https://ccm.net/apps-sites/software/2125-vba-using-the-like-operator-with-select-case/#using-the-true-expression-test).
For your purpose try this way

```
Select Case True
Case subShp.Characters.Text Like "*AA**"
ActiveWindow.Select vShp, visSubSelect
vShp.Cells("PinY").Formula = "80mm"
vShp.Cells("PinX").Formula = "180mm"
' iterate other conditions
End Select
```